# Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key of the @ManyToMany linked table

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a many to many relation between an entity `Function` and `Result` and I used an associative table called `Function_produces_result`.

[image: schema]

AbstractEntity.java:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@ToString
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

FunctionEntity.java:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "function")
@Getter
@Setter
public class FunctionEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    private String description;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "function_produces_result",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "function_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "result_id")
    )
    Set<ResultEntity> producedResults;
}
```

FunctionProduceResultEntity.java:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="function_produces_result")
@Getter
@Setter
public class FunctionProduceResultEntity extends AbstractEntity {
    
    private int rank;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "function_id", nullable = false)
    private FunctionEntity function;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "result_id", nullable = false)
    private ResultEntity result;
}
```

ResultEntity.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ResultEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String code;

    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String type;
}
```

FunctionInputEntity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="function_input")
@Getter
@Setter
public class FunctionInputEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private FunctionInputTypeEnum type;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "function_id", nullable = false)
    private FunctionEntity function;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
    private DriverEntity driver;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "function_result_id")
    private FunctionProduceResultEntity sourceResource;
}
```

When I launch the server I got this error:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK4t4snpmx4ck9oj8wkjxvjkg88:function_input [function_result_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (function_produces_result [function_id,result_id])
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.socgen.marvel.ego.Application.main(Application.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

There are similar questions such as [foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key for many-to-one mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728949/foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-the-referenced-primary-key-for-m) and [Hibernate MappingException: Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937114/hibernate-mappingexception-foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-the) but don't fix my problem.

Comment: Could you please also show `AbstractEntity` entity. What hibernate version do you use? I do not see any fields mapped by `@Id` ...

Comment: @SternK I edited the question and I added the `AbstractEntity`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to:

```java
@JoinTable(
            name = "function_produces_result",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "function_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "result_id")
    )
```

You tell Spring how the many-to-many relationship starts `FunctionEntity`s but have not provided an instruction that tells spring what the field `result_id` maps to on the other side (i.e. you've not specified where it ends), only that it is part of the many-to-many relationship.

To fix this you can add the following to your `ResultEntity` class definition:

```java
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "producedResults")
Set<FunctionEntity> functionEntities = new HashSet<>();
```

And it should work from what I can see online here: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3387643/java-persistence-with-jpa-and-hibernate-part-2-many-to-many-relationships.html

Answer (score 0):

In **FunctionInputEntity**, Hibernate expects both the foreign key references in it. Can you please try with the below?

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name = "function_id"),
       @JoinColumn(name = "result_id")
    })
private FunctionProduceResultEntity sourceResource;
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is that you try to mix up `@ManyToMany` [mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-unidirectional) with hidden linked table via `@JoinTable` and mapping via [linked entity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional-with-link-entity). Actually your linked table `function_produces_result` has the `id` primary key, but when you use the mapping via the `@JoinTable` annotation, hibernate assumes that linked table should have a composite primary key based on the foreign keys of the `@ManyToMany` association.

So, I would suggest you to rewrite the mapping of the `FunctionEntity` entity in the following way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "function")
public class FunctionEntity extends AbstractEntity
{
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "function")
   @MapKey(name = "result")
   private Map<ResultEntity, FunctionProduceResultEntity> producedResults;
}
```

It will simplify access to the `ResultEntity` entity from the `FunctionEntity` entity.